# DataGridView not refreshing after changing cell BackColor

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm populating a DataGridView from a List. In one of the columns I need to be able to change individual cells BackColor using ColorDialog.

I do this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2) {
        ColorDialog cd1 = new ColorDialog();
        if (cd1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            Color color = cd1.Color;
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = color;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the BackColor doesn't come up immediately but only after a mouse click to the DataGrid.

I tried with:

```
dataGridView1.Update();
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Nothing seems to work.

Is there any way to refresh the cell automatically after the color change?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the current cell after you changing the cell backcolor like this.

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
{
    ColorDialog colorDialog = new ColorDialog();
    if (colorDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Color color = colorDialog.Color;
        dgvExample.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = color;
        dgvExample.CurrentCell = dgvExample.CurrentRow.Cells[0];
    }
}
```